# Issue in Parsing Json image in C#

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2010, parsing

net C#. I am trying to parse Json from a webservice. I have done it with text but having a problem with parsing image. Here is the Url from where I m getting Json

```
http://collectionking.com/rest/view/items_in_collection.json?args=122
```

And this is My code to Parse it

```
using (var wc = new WebClient()) {
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var result = js.Deserialize<ck[]>(wc.DownloadString("http://collectionking.com/rest/view/items_in_collection.json args=122"));
foreach (var i in result) {
lblTitle.Text = i.node_title;
imgCk.ImageUrl = i.["main image"];
lblNid.Text = i.nid;
```

Any help would be great.
Thanks in advance.
PS: It returns the Title and Nid but not the Image.
My class is as follows:

```
public class ck
{    
public string node_title;
public string main_image;
public string nid;  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
 private static string ExtractImageFromTag(string tag)
 {
 int start = tag.IndexOf("src=\""),
    end = tag.IndexOf("\"", start + 6);
return tag.Substring(start + 5, end - start - 5);
}
private static string ExtractTitleFromTag(string tag)
{
int start = tag.IndexOf(">"),
    end = tag.IndexOf("<", start + 1);
return tag.Substring(start + 1, end - start - 1);
}
```

It may help

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are setting ImageUrl to something like this `<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://...` and not an actual url. You will need to further parse `main image` and extract the url to show it correctly.

**Edit**

This was a though nut to crack because of the whitespace. The only solution I could find was to remove the whitespace before parsing the string. It's not a very nice solution but I couldn't find any other way using the built in classes. You might be able to solve it properly using [JSON.Net](http://json.net) or some other library though.

I also added a regular expression to extract the url for you, though there is no error checking what so ever here so you'll need to add that yourself.

```
using (var wc = new WebClient()) {
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var result = js.Deserialize<ck[]>(wc.DownloadString("http://collectionking.com/rest/view/items_in_collection.json?args=122").Replace("\"main image\":", "\"main_image\":")); // Replace the name "main image" with "main_image" to deserialize it properly, also fixed missing ? in url
    foreach (var i in result) {
        lblTitle.Text = i.node_title;
        string realImageUrl = Regex.Match(i.main_image, @"src=""(.*?)""").Groups[1].Value;  // Extract the value of the src-attribute to get the actual url, will throw an exception if there isn't a src-attribute
        imgCk.ImageUrl = realImageUrl;
        lblNid.Text = i.nid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I tested this out after looking more closely at your json and it seems that your first problem is because of the whitespace in the element name `main image`. I'll look into this.

Comment: Yes it seems to be .. But as for as my knowledge is concern i think this whitespace can be handled but I don't know how to handle this whitespce. Do u ??

Comment: I need another example of Json to parse do u have any link which handle the json without whitespace ??

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working, though not a very nice, solution.

Comment: Well how to extract the src attribute??

Comment: Yes thats what the comment says on that line. Regular expressions are great for extracting data from strings.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21559/discussion-between-burhan-mughal-and-karl-johan-sjogren)