# Json image parsing

Tags: c#, .net, json, image

Hi here is my Json link from where i want to parse the image in my application

```
http://collectionking.com/rest/view/items_in_collection.json?args=122
```

The problem is this that while parsing it parse the text i.e. the title and nid but not the picture. Can any one help how to parse an object containing white space in it .. i.e. in my json there is an image named (Main image). this is the main problem.
here is my code to parse Json

```
using (var wc = new WebClient()) {
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var result = js.Deserialize<ck[]>(wc.DownloadString("http://collectionking.com/rest/node/122.json"));
    foreach (var i in result)
    {
        lblTitle.Text = i.node_title;
        lblNid.Text = i.nid;
        imgCk.ImageUrl = i.main_image;
    }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you show us your `ck` object? (the class)

Comment: public class ck
    {
        public string node_title;
        public string main_image;
        public string nid;

    }

Comment: thats no good, the JSON has `main image` not `main_image` (without the underscore), see my new answer, it fixes all your troubles...

Comment: You asked the exact same question a few hours ago and I gave you a working answer there, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001199/issue-in-parsing-json-image-in-c-sharp/14001245

Comment: Now if i want to parse json with query what i should do .. Take a look at this link. myhealthpal.com/charity_app/postal_code.php?q=EH14%201EB –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my new answer.

You will have a problem by using the `JavaScriptSerializer` as your incoming JSON is like this:

```
[
   {
      "node_title":"<a href=\"/item/brickell-point\">Brickell Point</a>",
      "main image":"<img typeof=\"foaf:Image\" src=\"http://collectionking.com/sites/default/files/styles/collection_list/public/BrickellPoint_front.jpg\" width=\"200\" height=\"250\" alt=\"\" />",
      "nid":"123"
   },
   {
      "node_title":"<a href=\"/item/flagler-street-bridge\">Flagler Street Bridge</a>",
      "main image":"<img typeof=\"foaf:Image\" src=\"http://collectionking.com/sites/default/files/styles/collection_list/public/FlaglerStreetBridge_Miami_River.Front_.jpg\" width=\"200\" height=\"250\" alt=\"\" />",
      "nid":"124"
   }
]
```

and there's the image property **with a space in it**... that's not accomplishable, so let's use [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) for this.

**Step 1** - Right click on `References` of your project and choose `Manage Nuget Packages` and in the "Online" tab, install JSON.NET

After that, use this code:

```
// grab information
using (var wc = new WebClient()) {
    json = wc.DownloadString(url);
}

// deserialize using JSON.NET
var result = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ck[]>(json);

// output
foreach (var i in result)
{
    lblTitle.Text = i.node_title;
    lblNid.Text = i.nid;
    imgCk.ImageUrl = i.main_image;}
}
```

and **remember to modify** your `ck` object to

```
public class ck
{
    public string node_title { get; set; }
    public string nid { get; set; }

    [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty(PropertyName = "main image")]
    public string main_image { get; set; }
}
```

where we use the `JsonProperty` to **map the correct attribute** that we are receiving.

To extract the title and image out of the tags, and cause I don't like RegEx, I use:

```
private static string ExtractImageFromTag(string tag)
{
    int start = tag.IndexOf("src=\""),
        end = tag.IndexOf("\"", start + 6);
    return tag.Substring(start + 5, end - start - 5);
}
private static string ExtractTitleFromTag(string tag)
{
    int start = tag.IndexOf(">"),
        end = tag.IndexOf("<", start + 1);
    return tag.Substring(start + 1, end - start - 1);
}
```

So you can use it your self as:

```
// output
foreach (var i in result)
{
    // for this example, let's grab the last 
    lblTitle.Text= ExtractTitleFromTag(i.node_title);
    lblNid.Text= i.nid;
    imgCk.ImageUrl= ExtractImageFromTag(i.main_image);
}
```

Now... **you do realize that** your `foreach` will only get the last entry of the receiving JSON right? as you're not

you should simply do:

```
foreach (var i in result)
{
    i.node_title = ExtractTitleFromTag(i.node_title);
    i.main_image = ExtractImageFromTag(i.main_image);
}
```

and use the DataGrid to show more than a entry, for example.

```
myDataGrid.Source = ck;
```

Comment: Thank You very Much for Your Help @ Balexandre

Comment: Now if i want to parse json with query what i should do .. Take a look at this link.  http://www.myhealthpal.com/charity_app/postal_code.php?q=EH14%201EB

Comment: Do something for yourself, or hire a professional if you dont know what to do. If you got that "Job" you need to prove yourself that you are worth it.

Comment: Ok that's fine actually I m learning Json Parsing. And one of my friend is doing Job so I m taking link from Him and try to solve the problems. Anyway thanx for Your help and advice

Answer (score 1):

The `main_image` attribute doesn't contain an image URL. Instead, it contains a piece of HTML, e.g.:

```
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://collectionking.com/sites/default/files/styles/collection_list/public/FlaglerStreetBridge_Miami_River.Front_.jpg" width="200" height="250" alt="" />
```

You can use regular expressions to extract the URL (it's not fool proof, but might work in most cases):

```
string imageUrl = null;
string htmlPiece = i.main_image;
Match m = Regex.Match(htmlPiece, "src=\"[^\"]+\"");
if (m.Success)
  imageUrl = m.Value.Substring(5, m.Value.Length - 6);
```

Comment: What error? Compile time error? Run-time error? What error message? Please be more specific. And what do you mean by "use the same code"? I don't understand it.